# Facebook: submitting a native Windows app for review

Tags: facebook

I built a native Windows app (non Windows-Store) that uses the Facebook API.

I wanted to make it public which means going through their review process which means (among other things) selecting the app's platform.

Sadly a native Windows app is not one of the choices: [Facebook app platform selection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgmIx.png)

I found 2 unanswered questions on SO on the same topic:
[one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217737/submit-app-detail-page-for-native-windows-8-application)
[two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236641/facebook-native-windows-app)

How should this be done in a proper way?

Thanks in advance.

PS:
I found a post a few days ago where the poster said he registered such an app by setting the platform to "web site" (I didn't keep the link).
This does not look like a good long term solution and also I don't have a domain to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you must set your platform to Web.

The reason for this can be found in the official documentation on [building your native logon flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3). There is no secure way of creating a logon flow without a server, as this would imply storing your App Secret inside your binary or app config file.

So the recommended (and only supported) way is to create a server which stores the App Secret and handles authentication for you. And use this server from the WebBrowser/WebView control which you embed into your native application.

This means you use the logon flow from a web browser via a custom server and you should have a domain for it (a domain is quite cheap nowdays, it should not be a problem). So you are building a web app embedded into a native app.

For a successful login review do the following:

1. Choose Web as your platform
2. On the Settings page in the Advanced tab choose Native App.
3. Create a screencast (*Start your app, logon, use all the requested permissions and that's it. Do not edit it!*) and upload it to the web (YouTube/Vimeo/...)
4. When submitting provide a link to your screencast.

Comment: Cheers @juhos. 

This has been sitting there unanswered for quite a while now and I have since abandoned that project but your answer is still good general knowledge.

I can't upvote your answer (not enough reputation) but I hope it will help future wonderers...

Comment: Thanks @Intraz, you might not be able to upvote, but you still can accept the answer (just click the check mark under the up/down vote buttons)... :)

Comment: There you go @juhos ;-)
Much deserved.