# What's the Facebook platform for native apps?

Tags: c#, facebook

I'm developing an Windows native app, that uses some functions from Facebook. However, my application must be reviewed by Facebook before it can be used by other people.

The problem is: I can't find a platform that matches my application, because:

- Obviously, it isn't an iOS, an Android, a XBox neither a PlayStation app
- It can't be accessed from Facebook, so it isn't an App on Facebook
- It can't be accessed online, so it isn't a Website.
- I have no idea on what is a Page Tab, but I assume it's involved with Facebook Pages, so it isn't related to my application either.
- And, while it is an Windows App, it isn't on the Windows Store, so I can't fill the required fields on it.

I've found some unanswered questions about that: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769185/how-to-specify-a-windows-desktop-platform-with-facebook-app) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452482/facebook-app-submission-platform-unclear) [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236641/facebook-native-windows-app) [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007672/facebook-submitting-a-native-windows-app-for-review) [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217737/submit-app-detail-page-for-native-windows-8-application)

In the last one, the OP said that he used "Website with Facebook Login". Will this work?

Comment: I am also curious about the answer.

Comment: Can you use the Windows Store beta process?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I don't think so, Fosco. My application, currently, is developed and runs under Windows 7, and it don't even have an Store. But thanks for helping!